# C# I18N - Is it possible to include language resource files without creating a dll?

Tags: c#, internationalization, resx

I'm working on converting some exiting code to take advantage of the Internationalisation tools in VS.Net 2005. I've been asked to do this without creating any additional dlls if at all possible. I've tried a few different things and searched around, but I'm not sure if this can be done, so I thought I'd ask you guys.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to take advantage of the i18n tools in VS.NET then you will have to use multiple assemblies (one for each culture).  However, you may be able to merge these assemblies using ILMerge for deployment.

I don't know if this will work, but at least it may give you another path to research.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to package all your internationalization resources in your main assembly, but this may have repurcussions for your versioning strategy.  You can point the `ResourceManager` constructor [at any assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5.aspx), including the currently executing one.